# How do I correctly use traits in a file separate to its implementation

Tags: rust, module, traits, implementation

I'm having a bit of a headache trying to use traits defined in separate files to the implementation and was hoping somebody could point out where I am going wrong.

My file structure is this

```
main.rs
file1.rs
thing.rs
```

Contents of main.rs

```
mod file1;
mod thing;

fn main() {
    let item : Box<dyn file1::Trait1> = Box::new(thing::Thing {});
}
```

file1.rs

```
pub trait Trait1 {    
}
```

thing.rs

```
mod file1 {
    include!("file1.rs");
}

pub struct Thing {    
}

impl file1::Trait1 for Thing {    
}
```

The error on compilation is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `thing::Thing: file1::Trait1` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:9:41
  |
9 |     let item : Box<dyn file1::Trait1> = Box::new(thing::Thing {});
  |                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `file1::Trait1` is not implemented for `thing::Thing`
  |
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn file1::Trait1`
```

As far as I can tell file1::Trait1 is implemented. If not, what have I actually implemented?

Answer (score 4):

```rust
mod file1 {
    include!("file1.rs");
}
```

By writing this in `thing.rs`, you have created a module, `thing::file1`, which is distinct from the top-level module `file1`. Thus, you have two distinct versions of your trait, `thing::file1::Trait1` and `file1::Trait1`.

This is almost never the right thing. As a general principle, **every `.rs` file (except for `main.rs`, `lib.rs`, and other crate root files) should have exactly one `mod` declaration**.

Delete the above code from `thing.rs`, and use `use` instead of `mod`, or a fully qualified path:

```rust
use crate::file1;
...
impl file1::Trait1 for Thing {
    ...
```

or

```rust
use crate::file1::Trait1;
...
impl Trait1 for Thing {
    ...
```

or

```rust
impl crate::file1::Trait1 for Thing {
    ...
```

In general, `mod` **defines a module**, and `use` **brings items into scope**. You write `mod` only once per module, and `use` wherever you want to refer to that module.